# Detect if a hyperlink has been clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently looking for a way to check for a way to detect when a hyperlink is clicked on a page and if so, creating a variable with that hyperlink object. Please take note that these are generated links and do not have a detectable ID.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to keep track of clicked hyperlinks
or are you looking for a way to check if hyperlinks are being monitored in the above way?

Comment: i'm looking for a way to monitor activity on the hyperlinks as I need to get the parent of it but only when clicked

Comment: Generated links can have detectable IDs as well. What have you tried so far?

Comment: So far I tried finding the actual row that the link is on but I am having issues filtering to specific ones and I wasn't sure where to start with actually detecting the click

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate "real" links with Javascript and detect the onClick event:

```
<span onclick="LinkToPage('http://www.google.com');" style='cursor:pointer;'>New Link</span>
```

Then you can write your LinkToPage function, read the link parameter as string and open the link wih this, for example:

```
document.location.href = linkParam;   (could e.g. contain 'http://www.google.com')
```

If you cannot generate these faked links, you could still use JQuery to convert normal `<a href="xyz">TEST</a>` into these JS links as above.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of atleast two ways.
The easiest would be attaching a listener with jQuery to keep track of clicks.
You have to chose whether you send every hyperlink click or a collection at some moment.

```
$('a').click(function () {    
//Logging Code prob using $(this).parent()
return true;
});
```

The other way would be keeping track of the requests at serverside and store the info.